# EC2 instance fails one health chack after recreating it from an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, health-check

I've bumped into this quite stressing issue recently, after recreating an EC2 instance from an AMI the instance was failing one of two reachability health checks. I wasn't able to log in via SSH with its key or via SSM.

Luckily I could access it via `EC2 serial console` (from the EC2 dashboard click on the instance, the *Connect* button and then the last option on the right).

Thankfully, a colleague of mine is a VM God, and spared me an aneurism. Here is what you should do if it ever happened to you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically a misconfiguration of the MAC address of the VM, which doesn't match the one of the new machine. Note that this happens rarely, but if it happens it is a pain.

Here's how to fix it:

1. Access the EC2 instance from the serial console
2. Try to ping google.com (to check the instance isn't able to connect to the internet)
3. Edit this file in the ubuntu instance `nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`
4. Comment out the `match` lines as below:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
#            match:
#                macaddress: 02:4e:ac:36:b6:88
#            set-name: ens5
    version: 2
```

5. Run `netplan apply`
6. Finally check if you can now ping google.com

Honestly, this is badly handled by AWS; but, you know, it is what it is. At least you have a way out of it here.